# What's an alternative to onComplete() for returning the first executed Future on Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing

Given two futures *f1* and *f2*, I'm trying to return the one that completes its execution first using this method:

```
def first[A](f1: Future[A], f2: Future[A]): Future[A] = ???
```

As an example of an implementation, a promise is used to fetch the first future that finish its computation, something like this:

```
def first[A](f1: Future[A], f2: Future[A]): Future[A] =

  val promise = Promise[A]()
  f1.onComplete(result1 => promise.tryComplete(result1))
  f2.onComplete(result2 => promise.tryComplete(result2))

  promise.future
```

But I was wondering, is there any other approach to this problem that doesn't use the `onComplete()` method? (e.g., using the `map()` or `flatMap()` methods instead).

How would this implementation look like?

That's it, thanks so much for the help! I'm a newbie in this futures topic in Scala so I'm struggling a lil' bit with this. Have a nice day!

Comment: [fisrtCompletedOf()](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#firstCompletedOf[T])?

Comment: As I always say the **Scaldoc** is your friend.